# how to restore selected values from the jqueryUI multiselect plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm using a jquery [UI-multiselect plugin](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/)

I was wondering if its possible to write a function in javascript that will restore the values selected after a page refresh.
**My html:**

```
<select id="users_select" class="items multiselect" multiple="multiple">  
  //list of countries here
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
var index; 
if (this.countries.restore) {
   this.items.attr("value", this.countries.members);
   index = this.countries.members;
   $('#users_select option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
 }
```

but i dont get to restore it somehow...any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You can use following methods for deselect/select all options in multiselect, in your case use 
'deselect_all' whichi is nuthing but restoring in effect.

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('deselect_all');

$('#your-select').multiSelect('select_all');
```